# LocalEntry value extended with spaces after restart on WSO2 ESB 4.8.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

got a problem using LocalEntry for storing installation-specific settings under WSO2 ESB 4.8.1.
After restarting WSO2, some spaces are normally added to the values of LocalEntries, breaking down parsing of numeric value.

Any fix or workaround would be appreciated.

PS AFAIK, it worked correctly in version 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a workaround when you get the local entry content from your mediation :

```
normalize-space(syn:get-property('NAME_OF_LOCAL_ENTRY'))
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup Jean-Michel! This function works for numeric and string properties perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

This is an already known bug and fixed in next release according to jira [1]..

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3101

Thanks,
Mohan